# Correct translation of "my father taught me to play football"?

Tags: translation

How would one translate "my father taught me to play football"? Being relatively new to the language I'm unsure about how to handle the structure. What verb would one use? Lernen? Any held would be appreciated.

Comment: Steht es nicht im Wörterbuch?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are several options.

The literal translation would use the verb **[lehren](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/lehren)**.

> Mein Vater hat mich gelehrt Fußball zu spielen.

or

> Mein Vater hat mich das Fußballspielen gelehrt.

As a native Austrian German speaker I would prefer using **[beibringen](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/beibringen)** in spoken language though:

> Mein Vater hat mir das Fußballspielen beigebracht.

... which sounds less formal to my ears.

The verb **lernen** means **to learn**, it is what the student does, not the teacher.

Comment: +1 for Hulk, beibringen is the correct term, the others just sound weird.

Comment: I don't think that anywhere in the German speaking world _lehren_ would be preferred over _beibringen_ in this context, at least in spoken language. If anybody disagrees, please add a comment.

Comment: It looks like one possible translation (not the best one!) is missing: "Mein Vater hat mir beigebracht, Fußball zu spielen". But this sounds a bit like "my father taught me that I should play football (not _how_ to play flootball)"

Comment: @WalterTross In my opinion, there's no other connotation and it clearly indicates that your father taught you how to play football. If you're unsure, however, you could say "Mein Vater hat mir beigebracht, wie man Fußball spielt."

Comment: I would say: Das Fußballspielen hat mir mein Vater beigebracht.

Answer (score 0):

"My father taught me to play football" is a weird sentence. It's simple past, so it needs a date/time which could have been mentioned in another phrase, like "My father taught me to play football when I was 6 years old."

The correct translation must be simple past too: Mein Vater brachte mir bei, Fußball zu spielen

I guess.....

Comment: Germans use simple past quite rarely...

Comment: Indeed. The simple past might be appropriate if you write your memoirs, but in any other context one would probably use perfect tense here.